# OpenSSH not cleaning up the domain socket upon termination

Tags: ssh, unix-sockets

I have a local unix socket tunneled to another unix socket on a remote instance over SSH:

```
ssh -N -L $HOME/my.sock:/var/run/another.sock
```

however, when I terminate ssh gracefully (i.e. ctrl+C or SIGTERM), the `$HOME/my.sock` remains. It looks like this is not cleaned up properly. Is there an option/flag for this?

This is problematic because if I run the command for the second time, it fails due to existing socket file. (I can't see a "reuse" flag/option either that’ll overwrite the existing socket file.) And I much rather don’t add a `rm -f $HOME/my.sock`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer, you can control this with a command line flag: `-o 'StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes'`

Long answer: See ssh_config(5):

```
 StreamLocalBindUnlink
         Specifies whether to remove an existing Unix-domain socket file for local or
         remote port forwarding before creating a new one.  If the socket file already
         exists and StreamLocalBindUnlink is not enabled, ssh will be unable to forward
         the port to the Unix-domain socket file.  This option is only used for port for‐
         warding to a Unix-domain socket file.

         The argument must be yes or no (the default).
```

Comment: Not had a chance to try it, but you might need to check whether the remote end needs the same configuration (but in sshd_config).

Comment: No, the remote doesn't need the same config. This is good enough, although it doesn’t clean up the socket upon terminating ssh client, which would be really nice too.

Comment: In my case too, the server `sshd_config` does need the same config set.

Comment: I *think* I figured it out. If you do remote forwarding (-R), you need it on the server, while the ssh_config setting affects local forwarding.